# AJAX isn't loading the other js and css style

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I wrote a short AJAX code which is getting Facebook contents from a PHP file (in the PHP file I have declared `class="gallery-img-link"` as `<a>` and `class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"` as `<img>`).

I have the `gallery-img-link` on the bottom of site as jQuery script, the problem is when I add those classes by hand its working fine, but when I try to load those by a AJAX get request it seems to doesn't work.

Should I use it in a `document.ready` function?

I have tried live as well, but that didn't helped at all.

```
                          $(document).ready(function(){
                            $(\'#loading-image\').show();
                              $.ajax({
                                method:\'get\',
                                url:\'ajax.php\',
                                success:function(data){
                                  $("#facebook").html(data);
                                    },
                                complete: function(){
                                 $(\'#loading-image\').hide();
                                }
                              });
                          });
```

Comment: Why are you escaping the selectors (`\'#loading-image\'`)?

Comment: Put your code into `<script> ... </script>` instead, and remove escape caracters.

Comment: Sorry guys I used as \' because its in PHP code, it is working fine, the problem is with classess etc.

Comment: There <script> are fully pasted in php code.

Comment: Then The Problem is not the JS Code ist the PHP File

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicly the problem was that the content has been loaded but the "photo java script file" wasnt waiting to get the page loaded, so this function couldnt work at all. Becasue those AJAX loaded after "reading JS function".

Answer (score 0):

For all JavaScript DOM manipulations you Need the DOM to be fully loaded.

Without having your PHP and other Code around I can just correct your JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#loading-image').show();
      $.ajax({
           method: get ,
           url: ajax.php ,
           success: function(data){
                $("#facebook").html(data);
           },
           complete: function(){
                $('#loading-image').hide();
           }
       });  
});
```

UPDATE:

Go Into the f12 Developer Tools in your Browser, and go to the Network Tab, then have a llok o all loaded Files, on should be `ajax.php`. Have a look what the File of that COntent is

Comment: The '\ thing is becasue I'm using massive php output as $msg .= '';

Comment: That script Returns: $msg .= ' ';

Comment: 2 Options: Put PHP Tags around and at th and `echo $msg;` OR remove all PHP code

Comment: @ j_s_stack didnt help at all.